# Whether the series is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I believe that the following is true, but can not prove:

The sum $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i(x_i-x_{i-1})$$ is convergent, whenever the sequence $\{x\}_{i=0}^\infty$ is convergent and the sequence $\{a\}_{i=1}^\infty$ is non-increasing and non-negative.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be [Abel's test for convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_test).

Comment: I think you may be able to modify the proof of Dirichlet's test [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) to provide a proof of your statement (Note $B_n=\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-x_{i-1})=x_n-x_0$ converges to $x-x_0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, where $x$ is the limit of $(x_i)$. So, in the second line of the proof in the link, we still have that $(a_{n+1}B_n)$ converges.). You could also prove your result directly using Dirichlet's Test applied to the sum $\sum c_n(x_i-x_{i-1})$ where $c_n=  a_n-\lim_i a_i  $.

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly Dirichlet's Test since

$$\begin{align*}(1)&\;a_{n+1}\le a_n\\(2)&\;\left|\sum_{k=1}^n(x_k-x_{k-1})\right|=\left|x_n-x_0\right|\le M+|x_0|\;\;,\;\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\end{align*}$$

with $\,M\,$ s.t. $\,|x_n|\le M\,\,\,\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\,$ .

Comment: [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) requires that $(a_n)$ has limit $0$. Without this assumption, additional assumptions on the $b_n$ are required (such as $\sum b_n$ is convergent, as we have here)

Comment: You are right, yet the correction is minor...I think, as the difference in only a constant. I may try to add something about this later. Thanks.